# Recieiving "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" on website page, never received before, how to get rid?

Tags: wordpress, google-api, widget

I can't get rid of the Over query limit messaging on my website and we have never exceeded it before. Not sure why we would now- we get only 2-300 users on our page daily so there is no way we would exceed this quota set by Google. We use the Google Maps API for finding our location and for Google Business reviews. Any conflicts there?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*How are you calling the API? Which Maps services/features are you using?  Which endpoint?  Are you a paying customer?  Which platform?  Have you looked into this with Google?  What king information are you querying?  How often?  Are there limits in place to prevent your users from overusing the API's?  How do you know that 1 user isn't making 1000 calls an hour?*

Honestly, even with that information, nobody outside of your company can figure it out, but you could start here:

---

## First, make sure you what what your usage limits *are*:

> https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/

---

## Now, do you know the ***4 ways*** you can exceed usage limits?

> https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits

### *An excerpt:*

> You can exceed the Google Maps APIs web services usage limits by:
>
> - Sending too many requests per day.
> - Sending requests too fast, i.e. too many requests per second.
> - Sending requests too fast for too long or otherwise abusing the web service.
> - Exceeding other usage limits, e.g. points per request in the Google Maps Elevation API.

---

After you fully understand what you're *allowed* to use,

## Check what you are *actually* using, on the *API Dashboard*:

> https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard?duration=P30D